# CSS dynamic Sticky footer required

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create an HTML form that is fixed to the bottom of the page. So when the user scrolls down, I want the input box to be fixed to the bottom.

But, when the user scrolls to a certain point (say 70% of the way down the page) I want the form to no longer be sticky, and to move up with the rest of the content.

Anyone got any ideas on how to do this using CSS/jQuery?

Comment: you need to use jquery scrolltop, rest of the codes u need to do it yourself. Comeback when you're stuck with your code.

Comment: Doesn't that just let you scroll to a certain element in the page? Don't think that's what I need?

Comment: no, what you are talking about is scrollTo. What I'm talking about is scrollTop

Comment: Okay. See what you mean. Yeah that will work. Thanks.

Comment: No idea why this question has been voted down already. It seems perfectly reasonable to ask in my opinion. I want to do X... can anyone suggest an approach to do X.  That's stack overflow for you.

Comment: google "js sticky" there are several super easy solutions out there

Comment: @dave this is voted down because no code. you should have used google first, tried something, be stuck then ask something specific here.

Comment: We really can't ask questions that don't have code? Can't see the benefit in that. What if someone has a question about design patterns. Don't see why every question should have to be accompanied by code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

$(window).scrollTop() will give you the top position of your view port. You can combine this with the $(document).height() to calculate your % of height your are currently viewing. Based on that set the position to the sticky element

```
var height = $(document).height();
var topPos = $(window).scrollTop();
var perCentage = topPos/height;
if(perCentage > 0.7){
 $('#sticky').css({'position','absolute','top':topPos});
}
else{
 $('#sticky').css('position','fixed');
}
```